# mock `readlines()` in python unit tests

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, python-mock

I am trying to mock a `readlines()` object in python unit tests. What I have so far is

```
class Sample:
    def read_file(filename):
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
```

I want to write a unit test for readlines() object.
So far, I have come up with the following.

```
TEST_DATA = "test\ntest2\n"
@mock.patch("builtins.open")
def test_open(mock_open):
    mock_open.side_effect = [mock_open(read_data=TEST_DATA).return_value]
    assert mock_open.side_effect == Sample.read_file()
```

My question here is, how do I assert the returned value of `mock_open` is the same as the returned value of the actual `read_file` function in the `Sample` class? This is where I am failing and not able to go any further. Any help on this is much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: `assert mock_open() == Sample.read_file()`?

Answer (score 1):

In [unittest.mock docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open) there is an example that may help you

Here is the docs example adapted to your code.

```
from unittest.mock import patch


class Sample:
    def read_file(filename):
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
        return lines

TEST_DATA = "test\ntest2\n"
def test_open(mock_open):
    with patch('__main__.open', mock_open(read_data=TEST_DATA)) as m:
        s = Sample()
        res = s.read_file('foo')

    assert res == TEST_DATA
```